# Synchronous vs asynchronous PWM modulation

Tags: pwm, power-electronics

According to Mohan/Power Electronics, asynchronous PWM modulation results in subharmonics that are very undesirable in most applications. We can use this type of modulation only if we choose a large number of mf. (mf stands for the frequency modulation ratio).

Are there any reasons to choose asynchronous PWM modulation over synchronous?

Comment: I didn't even know asynchronous PWM was a thing. How do you PWM without a clock? Are you talking about things like pulse skipping constant-on time and hysteretic control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplicity.

The subharmonics being discussed in chapter8  of Mohan is due to sum-difference type effects between the control and the carrier *IF* they are not synchronous.

In digital-based controls this is typically not a concern as these are internally managed. However in analogue controls or mix controllers, the possibility of such a beat exists. the condition is mf needs to be an integer

> Small mf (mf <= 21)
>
> eg... if the inverter output frequency an hence the freqnency of
>   vcontrol is 65.42Hz and mf=15, the triangle wave frequency should be
>   EXACTLY 15 x 65.42 = 981.3Hz

Answer (score 0):

The reason to choose an asynchronous PWM could be variable frequency output where one can still use a fixed frequency carrier. Variable frequency carrier is hard to implement.